# Bootstrap make textarea height match window height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I've seen many different responses on how to make Textarea height 100%. I understand that using the "height: 100%" on textarea will auto size it to the height of the container. I'm using bootstrap 4 alpha6 (but I think solutions would apply to bootstrap 3 as well) and I have couple form controls, arranged top down, with the textarea being the last control with a submit button at the bottom.

With bootstrap I have deep html structure and assemble my page using vuejs components. So, I'm trying to avoid setting every container starting from the body to the height=100% until I get to the textarea itself.

Is there a way to make the textarea auto-size itself in height to fill out the remaining window space. When I resize the window, the textarea shall expand or contract as well. I use the text area for users to input JSON code and I need to give them as much height space as possible on the screen size they are.

Thanks.

Comment: One way would be to calculate height of your all components on the page without textarea and apply proper height to textarea (window height minus all your components height - on page load and resize event).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can do it.

You will need to play a little bit with the clientHeight property and adjust the size accordingly.

I have used jQuery here.

To see it working, view this following snippet in fullscreen mode.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ResizeTextArea() {
    ClientHeight = window.innerHeight
    $("#myTextArea").height(ClientHeight - ($("#myForm")[0].clientHeight - $("#myTextArea")[0].clientHeight + 30));
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    ResizeTextArea();
  });
  ResizeTextArea()

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="myTextArea" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Responsive TextArea</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea id="myTextArea" class="form-control" rows="3" style="height:auto;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I need to figure out how to transform jQuery to plain javascript now because I'm using Vue.js and can't just put the jQuery into it's modules.